# How to rebase a particular commit over another commit?

Tags: git

[image]

Right now the main branch has the commit order 1,3,4. with 2 being a separate commit from 1.
I need the order to be 1, 2, 3, 4. How do I do it? I'm unable to figure out how to use rebase over here.
Thanks for the help

Comment: This is tough to handle, because it appears that one of the commit is actually a merge commit.  Even if you try an interactive rebase, you might have to re-resolve all the merge conflicts.

Comment: Easy, not necessarily minimal, way is to merge master, then rebase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a simple `git rebase`:

```
git checkout sumant # your current branch
git rebase origin/master
```

NOTES:

- you can replace `origin/master` with `c0fbd68`... it all points to the same commit :)
- your commit 2 can contain changes that conflict with your commits 3,4,... You'll have to solve these conflicts manually. `git` does what it can, but cannot resolve all conflicts automatically.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot.